# .Net Core Micro-Service Test Automation

Tags: .net-core, automated-tests, microservices, specflow

We are well into our journey down the road with micro-services (.net core apis with postgres dbs) and things are going well but I am beginning to question our automation test strategy and wanted to see if anybody has any better ideas/suggestions on how we could improve.
As an aside, its worth mentioning that we also unit test absolutely everything but this post is more concerned with automation.
Lets say we  have an api gateway and two services under that gateway (customer service and invoice service).
Excluding the UI which is also automated, our test team currently create Specflow projects within each micro-service solution and write tests for all api methods.
This approach works well and we get great independent service tests BUT it has a few problems

1. Its a lot of work. Our testers are in many cases writing a lot more code that the developers
2. We're double testing because we're testing the gateway which is many cases is just forwarding requests to a service and returning the response
3. As the tests are in each service they are run as part of the build pipeline and can often lead to interesting scenarios where tests clash between services when building (rare but happens)
4. Each service has its own datastore and as some tests invoke other services I'd like to start with a clean data set before ANY tests are run
5. We have a ratio of 2 developers for each tester and no scope to add more testers. Writing automation tests is the single biggest bottleneck in our process due to the amount of coding required (and fixing of data etc)

The approach I'm considering is:

1. Create a single test suite separate from the projects that tests all services one by one in order after restoring all service databases
2. Containerize everything so we can spin up a blank environment, run tests and close it down
3. Add this to the build pipeline for every service so we know when things break early

The problem for me is that as this project grows (20 - 30 services planned over the next 2 - 3 years) I think the tests will run so slow and the project become so big that it will be unmaintainable.
How does everybody else test their .net based micro-services?

Answer (score 0):

So, let me give you what we are doing with 15ish microservices ranging from Apis to Worker services to one Gateway Api.

In each of the Microservice Solutions we have unit tests. Since each microservice is basically a crud service for almost 99% of the stuff, we are interacting with database even on tests. So for each test suite (xUnit) we are spinning new database (running migrations, etc...) on a Test server (MSSQL, Redis) creating Topology for RabbitMQ, creating all the configurations on external services. Then the tests run, and for each method we do this. We create everything, then we drop everything.

That is unit testing. Then we have integration testing for Apis in isolation. What that means is that for Every Api, we have a IntegrationTest Project that will use the ApiClient that we created for each of them to verify that all is working.

This is all including the microservices.

Then, we have the Front Api (Gateway Api as somebody likes to call it) that is actually the one communicating with microservices. For this one, we have 2 types of tests, both are integration, but, one is written with xUnit, while the other is written in Specflow.

For integration tests, developers are writing those for testing different scenarios.

For specflow, basically, we have thousands of scenarios where business people are writing specflow documentation, and then the developers are implementing it.

It can be maintainable, but, you really need a lot of effort to keep everything up to date. Documentation is very important here so that you know how everything is working, what configurations are being used and how the whole system interacts with stuff.

This is just the way we tought was the best given the circumstances, but, I guess there are other approaches as well/.

Comment: Thanks - It sounds very similar to what we are doing other than your developers are writing the integration tests which would be my preferred route (albeit the developers disagree :)). In our business the testers are writing those tests but they are very much manual testers who are trying to write code so the velocity is low